# How to show item's details in a modal with bootstrap 4 and laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, eloquent, bootstrap-modal

I'm a beginner in laravel and bootstrap's world and this is maybe very simple... I'm wondering how to show a modal with some information that I have in my sqlite database.

This is my problem: I have a view that shows a list of elements and I'd like to be able to make this behaviour: show a modal with details about a row when clicking on it.

This is the view that I'm using:

```
  <!-- list all the lists -->
<div class="row">
    <h3>@lang('Available lists')</h3>
</div>
<table class="table table-dark table-hover display" id="listsTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="d-flex">
            <th class="col-8">@lang('Name of the list')</th>
            <th class="col-2 text-center">@lang('Number of students')</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @forelse ($lists as $list)
        <tr class="d-flex">
            <td class="col-8"> {{ $list['title'] }} </td>
            <td class="col-2 text-center"> {{ count(explode(",",$list['emails_list'])) }}</td>
        </tr>
        @empty
            <h4>No tienes listas.</h4>
        @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- List users modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="showList" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <input type=hidden id="id" name=id>
                <h4 id="showList" class="modal-title text-dark">@lang('List details'):</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body text-dark">
                <div class="listname"><p>@lang('List name'): </p><span></span></div>
                <div class="students"><p>@lang('Students'): </p><span></span></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">@lang('Close')</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I also have this function:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#listsTable').DataTable({
            searching: false,
            responsive: true,
            "autoWidth": false,
        });
        var table = $('#listsTable').DataTable();
        $('#listsTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            console.log('Modal opened');
            $(".listname span").text(table.row(this).data()[0]);
            $(".students span").text(table.row(this).data()[1]);
            $("#showList").modal("show");
        });
    } );
</script>
```

When I click on a row, nothing happens... I've also tried to do it with a button and I managed to show a modal but not the information about the row.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you use the standard modal window display mechanism in bootstrap?  Example Add tag <a> to <tr> `<a  data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#showList">`

Comment: I just tried that out but it didn't work... Should I add smt else to make it work?